# Python: How to force updates to class variables across references

Tags: python, class, variables

I am using a class to store all the constant values that will be referenced throughout my code, like:

```
class APIConstants(object):
    AUTH_FILE_DELIMITER = '|'
    AUTH_USERNAME_KEY_VALUE = 'Username'
    AUTH_PASSWORD_KEY_VALUE = 'Password'
    SRC_FILE_SRC_SYS_CD_KEY_VALUE = 'SourceSystemCode'
```

I am referencing this file in another program like so:

```
from APIConstants import APIConstants 

print(APIConstants.AUTH_FILE_DELIMITER)
```

which dutifully prints `'|'`.

The problem is that if I update the value of `AUTH_FILE_DELIMITER` in `APIConstants` to some other value, the value does not reflect in the calling program (which keeps printing `'|'`) unless I restart the kernel. Rerunning the `APIConstants` class does not help either.

Is there a reason why this is so and is there a way to force Python to read the latest value from the referenced class?

Comment: You will have to reload the `APIConstants ` module.

Comment: Please clarify what kind of setup do you have (calling program/kernel -- something IPython-related?) and possibly show the code you use to "re-run" the class. Generally, reloading the module that has your class (then re-importing the class) should do the trick.

Comment: How and where are you making changes to that class variables/constants? It should give new updated values **without reloading**. The namespace of a class is manually looked up each time a call like `Foo.bar` is made - which means, you're doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: @RenaeLider: I am simply updating the values and hitting save. I also tried running the class files but that does not seem to work.
FYI... I am running Python 2.7.9 on Canopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to used the `reload(referenced_object)` function.  Below is a simplified example for how to use it.

```
# Make a simple function that prints "version 1"
shell1$ echo 'def x(): print "version 1"' > mymodule.py

# Run the module`
shell2$ python
>>>   import mymodule  
>>>   mymodule.x()  
version 1

# Change mymodule to print "version 2" (without exiting the python REPL)
shell1$ echo 'def x(): print "version 2"' > mymodule.py

# Back in that same python session
>>>    reload(mymodule)  
>>>    mymodule.x()  
version 2
```

Comment: Minor nitpicking: you can't do `reload(referenced_object)` with any arbitrary object. The function expects a module as its argument, and if you need to reload any object, you have to figure out which module it came first (by knowing this in advance or using `referenced_object.__module__`). Also, if you have imported the object using `from spam import Ham` IIRC you'd need to re-import `Ham` to take effect, otherwise you'll still have reference to older class version - although I'm not completely sure of this and too lazy to test.

Comment: True: but in his case he was referring to his own imported object, which is why I didn't include module.object. But you are correct.  Good catch

Comment: @keelyn: Not sure why you got downvoted, but is there a way to find out if the module has changed between runs? I can write up something custom, but I am very new to Python and would not want to do something if it is accessible through an in-built function.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `from module import class`. This makes a copy of the variables in your current module. Use `import module`, then "module.class.variable" will not be a copy. If you update the original, this will change as well.

If you find this to verbose, move the constants outside of a class, then module.variable will be just as verbose as before.

See [from file import variable creates copies of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069147/from-file-import-variable-creates-copies-of-variables)

file APIConstants

```
class APIConstants(object):
    AUTH_FILE_DELIMITER = '|'
    AUTH_USERNAME_KEY_VALUE = 'Username'
    AUTH_PASSWORD_KEY_VALUE = 'Password'
    SRC_FILE_SRC_SYS_CD_KEY_VALUE = 'SourceSystemCode'

def foo(str):
    APIConstants.AUTH_FILE_DELIMITER = str
```

main program

```
import APIConstants

print(APIConstants.APIConstants.AUTH_FILE_DELIMITER)

APIConstants.foo('^')

print(APIConstants.APIConstants.AUTH_FILE_DELIMITER)
```

output

```
|
^
```

If you are modifying the APIConstants directly, try using the reload command.

```
>>> import APIConstants
>>> print(APIConstants.APIConstants.AUTH_FILE_DELIMITER)
|
>>> # Modify the file APIConstants.py
>>> reload(APIConstants)
>>> print(APIConstants.APIConstants.AUTH_FILE_DELIMITER)
^
>>>
```

Comment: I tried using APIConstants.APIConstants.AUTH_FILE_DELIMITER. Doing this does not refresh the value from the APIConstants file

Comment: Works for me. Added example.

Comment: You're right. I added the reload command in the __init__ function before using the values Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention how you are updating those constants - is it from that API module? Is it from a thread? Or, is it from the caller module itself?

I will, however, show you a couple of ways in which this kind of trouble wouldn't occur. Assume we have two modules in the same folder - **`caller.py`** and **`api.py`**

**This is the `api.py` module:**

```
class APIConstants(object):
    BLUE = "grapes"
    TIME = 60

def modify():
    # we'll call this from elsewhere
    APIConstants.BLUE = "sky"
    APIConstants.TIME = 30
```

**This is the `caller.py` module:**

```
from api import APIConstants, modify

print(APIConstants.BLUE, APIConstants.TIME)
modify()
print(APIConstants.BLUE, APIConstants.TIME)
```

**This is the output:**

```
grapes 60
sky 30
```

Clearly, the change did reflect in our output. Now, If there was a third module (say `patch.py`) that calls `modify` or make changes to the `APIConstants` in any way, it would still give you the correct (modified) results in your `caller.py` module.

Also, note that the `import api` vs `from api import APIConstants` have no effect on this whatsoever - it should work.

If you're making changes to the `api.py` during runtime. ie; if you are editing the file, then you have to reload that module (but why would you do that?)

If this is not what you're doing, leave a comment below and I shall update this answer accordingly.